Problem with UV on round object
I have created a model that I like but I have a problem with the UVs.
This is my base UVs.

But when I unwrap it it goes like this.

I'm new to Blender so I do not understand what to do.
What am I doing wrong?

Could you edit the question and describe the issue specifically? You say it "goes like this" - what exactly do you mean the problem is? How do you want it to be mapped exactly and how does the result you get now differ from your expectations?

If that last sentence that you added to your question means that you fixed the problem, please add that explanation as a seperate answer rather than just adding it to your question. Thanks.

I fixed the problem by just applying the scale of my object.
